# why -fsanitizer=address gives me an error while making two dimensional array using malloc?

Tags: c, while-loop, dynamic-memory-allocation, pointer-arithmetic

I was trying to make a to dimensional array using malloc
But when I tried compiling the file using ' gcc *.c -g -fsanitize=address (file_name)'
this shows me an error of

```
0x604000000cfb is located 0 bytes to the right of 43-byte region [0x604000000cd0,0x604000000cfb)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x10ab6b17d in wrap_malloc+0x9d 

(libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x4917d)

   #1 0x10ab0f64f in set_space make_database.c:60

   #2 0x10ab10750 in main rush.c:78

   #3 0x7fff695b2cc8 in start+0x0 (libdyld.dylib:x86_64+0x1acc8)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow make_database.c:81 in store_line
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
```

the #1 line points '*arr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (each_len[i] + 1))

But I think there is no error in my code. Can you help me??

```
// total_line is 41
    arr = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (total_line + 1));
    while (i < total_line)
    {   
// each_len is an integer array that stores length of each line.
        *arr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (each_len[i] + 1));
        i++;
        arr++;
    }
    *arr = malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);
'''
```

Comment: Also I can't free my allocated space... What am I missing?

Comment: Note that you have lost the original value of `arr` returned by `malloc`. So you can't `free` it (or even use it for anything)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this `while` loop ( I assume that the variable `i` was set to `0` before the loop)

```
while (i < total_line)
{   
    // each_len is an integer array that stores length of each line.
    *arr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (each_len[i] + 1));
    i++;
    arr++;
}
```

the pointer `arr` is changed, which initially pointed to the allocated array of pointers.

Instead you could write

```
while (i < total_line)
{   
    // each_len is an integer array that stores length of each line.
    arr[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (each_len[i] + 1));
    i++;
}

arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);
```

Pay attention to that the array `each_len` shall contain initialized elements no less than `total_line`.